# Strange issue with Material PagerSlidingTabStrip, FragmentPagerAdapter, and BackStack management

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am creating [Scrollable Tabs per the Material Design guidelines](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-types-of-tabs), but I run into a strange issue when I switched from a `PagerAdapter` to a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. This issue only occurs after I have navigated to my tab fragment, hit back, then navigated to it again.

A screen recording of the issue is visible at [this URL](https://vid.me/SGVe).

I am using this library: [jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/jpardogo/PagerSlidingTabStrip/blob/master/library/src/com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.java) for my fragments. This is the code on how I am instantiating this fragment.

```
@OnItemClick(R.id.home_list_listview)
     void onItemSelected(int position) {
         getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.container, new SlidingFragment())
                 .addToBackStack(null)
                 .commit();
     }
```

Am I missing something basic in the fragment lifecycle here? `SlidingFragment` is just a blank fragment, so it doesn't need to be constructed in a special way. I'm trying to pinpoint whether it's a bug in the library or my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was having some issues with `OnDestroyItem()`. I switched to a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and everything works great now